# How to set iframe scope shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

here is my code:

```
<iframe src="http://bing.com" style="width:100%; height:500px;"/>
<script>
  $(document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document).on("keydown", function () {
    console.log("prpr")
  })
</script>
```

when i focus in iframe and hit keyboard, the keydown func isn't be triggered, how to set shortcut for iframe document? Exist sof questions don't fix my question

Comment: you need to add the handler from inside the framed page, not from "above". Just add a script tag with your code to the framed page.

Comment: @dandavis You mean iframe.document.addEventListener?

Comment: you be be using `document.addEventListener` from inside the frame. if you can't change the code in the frame, you can't do what you ask.